# Pandas: group and custom transfrom dataframe long to wide

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in following form:

```
+---------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
| payment | type  |  err  | country | source  |
+---------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
| visa    | type1 | OK    | AR      | source1 |
| paypal  | type1 | OK    | DE      | source1 |
| mc      | type2 | ERROR | AU      | source2 |
| visa    | type3 | OK    | US      | source2 |
| visa    | type2 | OK    | FR      | source3 |
| visa    | type1 | OK    | FR      | source2 |
+---------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'payment':['visa','paypal','mc','visa','visa','visa'], 
             'type':['type1','type1','type2','type3','type2','type1'],
             'err':['OK','OK','ERROR','OK','OK','OK'],
             'country':['AR','DE','AU','US','FR','FR'],
             'source':['source1','source1','source2','source2','source3','source2'],
             })
```

My goal is to transform it so that I have group by `payment` and `country`, but create new columns:
`number_payments` - just count for groupby,
`num_errors` - number of `ERROR` values for group,
`num_type1`.. `num_type3` - number of corresponding values in column `type` (only 3 possible values),
`num_source1`.. `num_source3` - number of corresponding values in column `source` (only 3 possible values).

Like this:

```
+---------+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| payment | country | number_payments | num_errors | num_type1 | num_type2 | num_type3 | num_source1 | num_source2 | num_source3 |
+---------+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| visa    | AR      |               1 |          0 |         1 |         0 |         0 |           1 |           0 |           0 |
| visa    | US      |               1 |          0 |         0 |         0 |         1 |           0 |           1 |           0 |
| visa    | FR      |               2 |          0 |         1 |         2 |         0 |           0 |           1 |           1 |
| mc      | AU      |               1 |          1 |         0 |         1 |         0 |           0 |           1 |           0 |
+---------+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I tried to combine pandas groupby and pivot, but failed to make all and it's ugly. I'm pretty sure that there are some good and fast methods to do this..
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use get dummies and then select the 2 grouper columns and create the group, then join the size with sum:

```
c = df['err'].eq("ERROR")
g = (df[['payment','country']].assign(num_errors=c,
                   **pd.get_dummies(df[['type','source']],prefix=['num','num']))
 .groupby(['payment','country']))
out = g.size().to_frame("number_payments").join(g.sum()).reset_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

  payment country  number_payments  num_errors  num_type1  num_type2  \
0      mc      AU                1           1          0          1   
1  paypal      DE                1           0          1          0   
2    visa      AR                1           0          1          0   
3    visa      FR                2           0          1          1   
4    visa      US                1           0          0          0   

   num_type3  num_source1  num_source2  num_source3  
0          0            0            1            0  
1          0            1            0            0  
2          0            1            0            0  
3          0            0            1            1  
4          1            0            1            0
```

Answer (score 2):

First it is better to clean the data for your stated purposes:

```
df['err_bool'] = (df['err'] == 'ERROR').astype(int)
```

Then we use `groupby` for applicable columns:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['country','payment']).agg({
        'number_payments' : 'count',
        'err_bool':sum})
```

Then we can use the pivot for `type` and `source`:

```
df['dummy'] = 1
df_type = df.pivot(
    index=['country','payment'], 
    columns='type', 
    value='dummy', 
    aggfunc = np.sum
)

df_source = df.pivot_table(
    index=['country','payment'], 
    columns='source', 
    value='dummy', 
    aggfunc = np.sum
)
```

Then we join everything together:

```
df_grouped = df_grouped.join(df_type).join(df_source)
```

Comment: There are many errors in your code. The columns in `agg` doesn't exist, there is no `dummy` value during `pivot`, and `pivot` doesn't accept `aggfunc`.

Comment: You are right regarding the `dummy` column. However, `agg` and  `aggfunc`, they are part of the core pandas. If you are encountering error, then you need to check whether pandas is installed correctly:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: That's `pivot_table`. You are using [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html). And i said the columns in `agg` doesn't exist, not the function `agg` doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, my bad:( . Seems I am depending too much on IDEs